# Convert a time feature to pd.to_datetime() format

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to convert my feature but I get value error 
`ValueError: time data '21OCT17:00:00:00' does not match format '%d%m%H:%M:%S:%f' (match)`.
In the feature values presented in this format `18APR17:00:00:00`. What's wrong with my format parameter in `pd.to_datetime()`?

```
    df_train['TRDATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['TRDATETIME'],
                                            format='%d%m%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
df_train['TRDATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['TRDATETIME'],
                                            format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S')
```

- %b == Month as locale’s abbreviated name.Ex: Jan, Feb
- %y == Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.Ex: 17, 18